# Rails undefined method returned through has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, undefined, has-many

I'm running into a bit of an issue here that I don't quite understand. Rails 3.1.

I have two classes linked with a has_many relationship Books and Data:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :data, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Datum < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :books

def file_path
    u = @book.path + '/' + self[:name] + '.' + self[:format]
    return u
end
end
```

The relationship works correctly and in my view I can extract attributes from the Datum class correctly.
From the view:

```
<% book.data.each do |d| %><%= d.format %><% end %>
```

This works perfectly. But when I try to reference the method that returns the path I get an undefined method error.

```
<% book.data.each do |d| %><%= d.file_path %><% end %>
```

I'm obviously missing something very basic here...

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
def file_path
    u = book.path + '/' + self[:name] + '.' + self[:format]
    return u
end
```

Notice that I'm using `book` instead of `@book`

Answer (score 0):

Your `belongs_to` relationship is not correct. Also, you can't access `@book` in your model. Your `Datum` model should look like

```
class Datum < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :book

  def file_path
    return book.path + '/' + self[:name] + '.' + self[:format]
  end
end
```

Since `Datum` belongs to a `book`. The `book` in `Datum` model will refer to a particular book that this datum belongs to.

Comment: Hmmm. Now the error returned is: "undefined method `book' for #<Datum:0x00000002d62570>"

Comment: OK - after a little more poking around, I've come up with the following: by adding `book = Book.find(self[:book_id])` in the Data class method, I manually search for the parent Book object. This works, but seems like the information should already be available and I also see that this is forcing extra SQL requests against the DB for each Book object.

Comment: Could you try accessing `self.book ` in file_path method?